# proc transreg not outputting curve fit plot

Tags: sas, regression, ods, sas-studio

I am using proc transreg to test different transformations in the sashelp.baseball dataset. I request all plots and sometimes I can see a curve fit graph and sometimes I can't. Is there something I am missing if I want to output the regression fit with the code below?

```
DATA BASEBALL;
    SET SASHELP.BASEBALL;
RUN;

ODS GRAPHICS ON;
ODS OUTPUT
    NObs = num_obs
    FitStatistics = fitstat
    Coef = params
    ;
PROC TRANSREG
    DATA=BASEBALL
    PLOTS=ALL
    SOLVE
    SS2
    PREDICTED;
    ;
    MODEL_1:
        MODEL POWER(logsalary/parameter=1) = log(nruns);
            OUTPUT OUT = fitted_model;
RUN;
```

For clarity, the regression fit plot is a scatter plot with the estimated regression line fitted through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fit plot is generated when the dependent variable does not have a transformation. You can create the transformation ahead of time to get this graph then.

From [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_transreg_details51.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en):

> ODS Graph Name: FitPlot
>
> Plot Description: Simple Regression and Separate Group Regressions
>
> Statement and Option: MODEL, a dependent variable that is not
>   transformed, one non-CLASS independent variable, and at most one CLASS
>   variable

This code works for me:

```
PROC TRANSREG
    DATA=sashelp.BASEBALL
    PLOTS=ALL
    SOLVE
    SS2
    PREDICTED;
    ;
    MODEL_1:
        MODEL identity(logsalary) = log(nruns);
            OUTPUT OUT = fitted_model;
RUN;
```

And generates the desired graph.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, makes sense - I was hoping that power(dependent_var/parameter=1) would not be considered a transformation.

Thank you

Comment: How to add an equation into the plot?